# Using a trait as phantom type

Tags: rust, phantom-types

In Rust, I want to use a phantom type to properly type a simple id:

```rust
struct Id<T> {
    val: u32,
    _type: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

In a first draft version, I used concrete structs as `T`, all was well. Then in a more elaborate version using differents data sources, those structs became traits. Let's say:

```rust
trait MyArticle {
    fn get_id() -> Id<MyArticle>;
}
```

But using traits as phantom types brings problems:

- The compiler makes me declare `T: ?Sized`, as if the size of `T` was potentielly needed. I could live with that, but as the purpose of `PhantomData<T>` is to tell that `T` won't be used, I wonder if there is some other way?
- I get the warning: "trait objects without an explicit 'dyn' are deprecated". I can get rid of it with global `#![allow(bare_trait_objects)]`, but this warning is otherwise useful and I don't want to do that. Is there a way to allow `bare_trait_object` *only* "when used as the type parameter for `Id<T>`"?

My current solution is to duplicate name types between an empty struct and a trait:

```rust
struct MyArticle_ {};

trait MyArticle {
    fn get_id() -> Id<MyArticle_>;
}
```

This is awkward but I could not find better.

Comment: I suspect you want `fn get_id() -> Id<Self>;`

Comment: Good question, but actually no. The typing of Ids is quite everywhere in the code using the traits; there are several kinds of "articles" that each is a trait, but the relationships beween those articles are well-known. It would be tedious to let everything get a generic or associated type only to be able to use it as a phantom type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your sample lies in understanding what the trait is. And in fact it is **not** a type (that's why compiler asks for `T: ?Sized`), but a requirement for a type. Thus the solution is fairly simple: come up with a "real" type. You got it right with a struct declaration, it can be one option. But usually it's much more convenient to use associative type for that:

```rust
trait MyArticle {
    type T;

    fn get_id() -> Id<Self::T>
    where
        Self::T: MyArticle;
}

// so given impls
struct X;

impl MyArticle for X {
    type T = u32;
    fn get_id() -> Id<u32> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl MyArticle for u32 {
    type T = u32;
    fn get_id() -> Id<u32> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

So finally, you're able to call `X::get_id()`, or a fully-qualified version: `<X as MyArticle>::get_id()`

Also, you may read [there](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) why `fn get_id() -> Id<Box<dyn MyArticle>>` doesn't work.

Comment: A trait is technically not a type! Now that you wrote it, it seems obvious, but it was my error indeed. The associated type is a good idea, I think it will be adequate in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that traits are not themselves types, although `dyn Trait`s are. So when you write `Id<MyArticle>`, it actually means `Id<dyn MyArticle>` (hence the warning), and it wouldn't compile if `MyArticle` is not object safe.

In this particular case you can make `MyArticle` object-safe:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Id<T: ?Sized> {
    val: u32,
    _type: PhantomData<T>,
}

trait MyArticle {
    fn get_id() -> Id<dyn MyArticle> where Self: Sized;
}
```

If you couldn't or don't want to make the trait object-safe, then I think your empty struct solution is the way to go. Note that if you just need an empty struct you can use just write `struct MyArticle_;`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was useful, too.